# Python numpy.var returning wrong values

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to do a simple variance calculation on a set of 3 numbers:

```
numpy.var([0.82159889, 0.26007962, 0.09818412])
```

which returns

```
0.09609366366174843
```

However, when you calculate the variance it should actually be

```
0.1441405
```

Seems like such a simple thing, but I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) explains:

```
ddof : int, optional
    "Delta Degrees of Freedom": the divisor used in the calculation is
    ``N - ddof``, where ``N`` represents the number of elements. By
    default `ddof` is zero.
```

And so you have:

```
>>> numpy.var([0.82159889, 0.26007962, 0.09818412], ddof=0)
0.09609366366174843
>>> numpy.var([0.82159889, 0.26007962, 0.09818412], ddof=1)
0.14414049549262264
```

Both conventions are common enough that you always need to check which one is being used by whatever package you're using, in any language.

Comment: Thanks!  I just figured it out before I came back to check out the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`np.var` by default calculates the population variance.

The Sum of Squared Errors can be calculated as follows:

```
>>> vals = [0.82159889, 0.26007962, 0.09818412]
>>> mean = sum(vals)/3.0
>>> mean
0.3932875433333333
>>> sum((mean-val)**2 for val in vals)
0.2882809909852453
>>> sse = sum((mean-val)**2 for val in vals)
```

This is the population variance:

```
>>> sse/3 
0.09609366366174843
>>> np.var(vals)
0.09609366366174843
```

This is the sample variance:

```
>>> sse/(3-1)
0.14414049549262264
>>> np.var(vals, ddof=1)
0.14414049549262264
```

[You can read more about the difference here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance)